# HTML Formatted Emails not displayed in gmail

Tags: c#, email

When Im trying to generate HTML Formatted Result set and sending the resultset as Email using SMTPsettings,Its working fine in Outlook but the same htmlformat is not displayed in gmail It displays as a plain Text.

```
public void GenerateRpt()
        {
            DataSet ds= new DataSet();
            //Result set is assigned to the dataset object.
            if ds[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                return;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    builder.Append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");
                    builder.Append("<head>");
                    builder.Append("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />");
                    builder.Append(" <style type='text/css'> @page {} table { border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;empty-cells: show} ");
                    builder.Append(" .Default { font-family: Calibri;background-color: transparent;border-style: none;vertical-align: bottom;margin-left: 0in;");
                    builder.Append(" writing-mode: page;color: #000000;font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal;text-shadow: none; text-decoration: none ! important;font-weight: normal;}");
                    builder.Append(" .ce2 { background-color: #95b3d7;border-width: 0.0349cm;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;color: #000000;font-size: 11pt;");
                    builder.Append("font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-left: 0in;text-shadow: none;font-family: Calibri;text-decoration: none ! important;");
                    builder.Append("vertical-align: middle;writing-mode: page;text-align: center ! important;}");
                    builder.Append(" .ce5 { background-color: transparent;border-width: 0.0349cm;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;color: #000000;font-size: 11pt;");
                    builder.Append("font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin-left: 0in;text-shadow: none;font-family: Calibri;text-decoration: none ! important;");
                    builder.Append("vertical-align: middle;writing-mode: page;text-align: center ! important;}");
                    builder.Append(" .ce6 { background-color: #a6a6a6;border-width: 0.0349cm;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;color: #000000;font-size: 11pt;");
                    builder.Append("font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;margin-left: 0in;text-shadow: none;font-family: Calibri;text-decoration: none ! important;");
                    builder.Append("vertical-align: middle;writing-mode: page;text-align: center ! important;}");
                    builder.Append(" .ce13 { background-color: transparent;border-width: 0.0349cm;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000;color: #000000;font-size: 11pt;");
                    builder.Append("font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;margin-left: 0in;text-shadow: none;font-family: Calibri;text-decoration: none ! important;");
                    builder.Append("vertical-align: bottom;writing-mode: page;}");
                    builder.Append(" .contentText {font-size: 11pt;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;font-style: Calibri;font-weight: bold;COLOR: #cccccc;");
                    builder.Append("</style>");
                    builder.Append("</head>");
                    builder.Append("<body>");
                    builder.Append("<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width='70%'> ");
                    builder.Append("<tr class='ro1'><td colspan='4'><b><p>RPT NAME</p></b></td></tr>");
                    builder.Append("<tr class='ro1'>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce2'><p>COL1</p></td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce2'><p>COL2</p></td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce2'><p>COL3</p></td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce2'><p>COL4</p></td>");
                    builder.Append("</tr>");
                    string tempdrow = string.Empty;
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        builder.Append("<td class='ce5'>");
                        builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Col1"].ToString() + "</p>");
                        builder.Append("</td>");
                        builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                        builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Col2"].ToString() + "</p>");
                        builder.Append("</td>");
                        builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                        builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Col3"].ToString() + "</p>");
                        builder.Append("</td>");
                        builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                        builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Col4"].ToString() + "</p>");
                        builder.Append("</td>");
                        builder.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                    // When No more records in the Dataset show the Grand Total.
                    builder.Append("<tr class='ro2'>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                    builder.Append("<b><p>GRAND TOTAL </p></b>");
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                    builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["Col2"].ToString() + "</p>");
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                    builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["Col3"].ToString() + "</p>");
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                    builder.Append("<td class='ce13' style='text-align: center'>");
                    builder.Append("<p>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["Col4"].ToString() + "</p>");
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                    builder.Append("</tr>");
                    builder.Append("</table>");
                    string sVehRejsubject = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subject"].ToString();
                    sendmail(builder.ToString(), sVehRejsubject);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Message();

                }

            }

        }

// Mail Sending Part


void sendmail(string strResultSet,string strRptType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (strResultSet.ToString() != "")
                {
                    string strMessage1 = string.Empty, TestEmp = "Mani";
                    strMessage1 = strResultSet.ToString();
                    strMessage1 += "<br><br><font color='blue'><b>Date:</b></font> " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "<BR>";
                    strMessage1 += "<br>Regards,<BR><BR>";
                    strMessage1 += TestEmp + "</b><br>";
                    <BR></td></tr></table></body></html>";

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                   //SMTP SETTINGS DEFINED IN APP.CONFIG FILE
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient _client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    string sFrom = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailFrom"].ToString();
                    string sTo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailTo"].ToString();
                    string sCC = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailCC"].ToString();
                    string sBCC = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailBCC"].ToString();
                    string sDisplayName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailFromDisplayName"].ToString();
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(sFrom, sDisplayName);
                    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(sTo));
                    if (sCC.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(sCC);
                    }
                    if (sBCC.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        mail.Bcc.Add(sBCC);
                    }
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Subject = strRptType + " AS ON - " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    mail.Body = strMessage1;
                    _client.Send(mail);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Ex.Message();
                return;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Email providers, does not allow the entire spectrum of html tags to be included in a message. In case you try to include an unsupported tag it will be ignored or automatically changed to another tag.

It is the same with unsupported css attributes.

For example `<br/>` is not allowed and will be ignored

What you should do is use universally supported Html tags only.

I've found [this](http://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support) page which lists the universally supported html tags and css attributes

Good luck !